# Web services clients in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I'd like you to list all the solutions available to generate web-service clients in Java platform.

I need to extract the structured information from the web-service to work with.

What do we have in the box? Preferably available as Eclipse plugins.

- Axis2
- JBossTools
- Apache CXF

What else ?

The problem here is that most tools do not work with web-services I need to consume.

Apache CXF does not generate the client.
JBoss only partially does the job.

I would like to try something and find what really works with particular web services.

Comment: Rather than Eclipse plugins have a look at Maven plugins (or even Ant tasks).. They make your build system independent of tools and more portable.

Comment: What's the value in just listing tools?  If you'd like a recommendation, then there are existing questions that have been asked about that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227643/web-services-clients-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109632/java-web-service-client http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291847/consuming-a-web-service-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289977/recommended-framework-for-java-web-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one gave a clear answer yet.
I got one advice: always try different versions of a framework, and try the latest.
It may sometimes be the key answer.

Answer (score 1):

java.sun.com/webservices/.../wsit/.../Examples_glassfish6.html

this is for creating web services